# Access database with LINQ, datatype conflict

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I am trying to access data from my database with LINQ but I am running into a data type error.

Here is my code:

```
public static String GetCheckIfCsIsRunning()
{
    using (Entities db = new Entities())
    {
        Stringl status = (from stat in db.Messenger_Settings
                          where stat.Id == 1
                          select stat.SettingValue);
        return status;
    }
}
```

I am currently getting an error at

```
where stat.Id == 1
```

saying

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'
```

I am trying to select from my table the ID of the row but the line of code is saying the Id is type bool? Perhaps the 'status' variable of the code creates 'stat' into a bool type. But how would I select the row according to Id?

my table structure is

ID(int) | Name(varchar) | SettingValue(varchar)

***EDIT***

I forgot to add an extra '=' ('=' --> '==')

***EDIT-2***

replaced int's with bool's new error occurs
   - data I want to access is varchar (select stat.SettingValue)

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.LINQ.IQueryable,string.' to 'string'
```

Comment: You get the same error at the same line, "cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'bool'?

Comment: @JimDagg sorry it took a while for my Visual Studio to load a proper fix. I get a different error now! Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you let us know what the error message is and where it occurs, we'll probably be able to hep you solve that problem too.

Comment: You're trying to assign SettingValue, which you state is a char value, back to a bool.  You're also not selecting a single value via First, FirstOrDefault, or any other mechanism.  If you would specify what you're actual intent is, you might be able to use a .Any() or you need to change your variable type and method signature.

Comment: @Liondancer I've addressed your new problem in an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're mistakenly using an assignment operator (=) in place of an equality operator (==).

Your line

```
where stat.Id = 1
```

actually *assigns* 1 to `stat.ID`, not what you want at all; then, the assignment returns the value assigned, in this case 1.  Since C# won't implicitly convert an `int` to `bool`, you get the error you see.  What you want to do is instead use `==`, the equality operator, which will do what you expect:  check if the value of stat.Id is 1 and return true or false.

Also, for future reference, you can avoid accidental assignment errors like this by using a different programming idiom:  put the constant first, i.e.

```
1 = stat.Id
```

While you'd still get an error either way here, in other cases where you do an accidental assignment, or in languages that *will* implicitly convert `int` to `bool` (which would be a runtime error that's hard to track down), you'll instead get an error, since you can't assign a value to a numeric literal like 1.

---

Per your edit, LINQ always returns a "lazy-loaded" query.  As soon as you try to access any elements in that query, it enumerates it.  An [IQueryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) is the object representation of that query.  Since we know that the query represents a sequence of `string`s (0 or more), we can call one of a few methods against `IQueryable<string>` to get at the results:

- `.First()` will return the first element in the sequence, and throw if the sequence has no elements.
- `.FirstOrDefault()` will return the first element in the sequence, or a default value if the sequence contains no elements.
- `.Single()` will return the element if there is only one element in the sequence, and throw otherwise (if there are zero or more than one element).
- `.SingleOrDefault()` will return the element if there is only one element in the sequence, a default value if there are no elements, or throw if there are more than one.

Which one to choose depends on your database schema as well as your application's desired behavior.  If you know there will only ever be one and exactly one value for a setting, use `.Single()`, so that you can error out and detect if you get several results.  If there *might* be a value for a setting (or it might not be defined), use `.SingleOrDefault()`.  And if a setting could have several values in the table, use `.First()` or `.FirstOrDefault()`.

In any case, what you'll get is either a `string` or a runtime exception in the case of unexpected results.

Answer (score 2):

`=` is an assignment operator.

You want to compare two values using the `==` comparison operator.

Answer (score 1):

I can see two issues here.

First of all you are trying to pass a string (varchar) to an int.

Second the LINQ you have will produce something like IEnumerable or IQueryable which won't be able to go to an int.

You should probably consider getting `First`, `FirstOrDefault`, `Sinle`, `SingleOrDefault`

Answer (score 1):

`where stat.Id = 1` needs to be `where stat.Id == 1`

You're attempting to set the value rather than doing a comparison.